# Unable to resume Activity..java.lang.NullPointerException in Log in Twitter

Tags: android, twitter, nullpointerexception, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I try to write an application that can be log in on twitter. My library is Twitter4j. The code work until the method `onResume` is called.
The

`exception(Unable to resume Activity...NullPointerException)` is at this line in the method

`onResume():`

```
AccessToken acc = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken,verifier);
```

But i don't understand where is my error. Someone can help me??

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Twitter twitter;
    private RequestToken requestToken;
    private static RequestToken re;
    final public static String CALLBACK_URL = "app://casa";
    private RequestToken priv = null;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new updateTwitterStatus().execute();

            }
        });

    }

    class updateTwitterStatus extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String testStatus = "prova tweet ";

            ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();

            cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
                    .setOAuthConsumerKey("******")
                    .setOAuthConsumerSecret(
                            "*******");

            try {
                TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
                twitter = tf.getInstance();
                Log.i("bauu", "miao");
                requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(CALLBACK_URL);
                String authUrl = requestToken.getAuthenticationURL();

                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())));


                return authUrl;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {


        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Uri uri = this.getIntent().getData();
        Log.i("callback funziona", "ciao");
        if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(CALLBACK_URL)) {
            final String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");

            // c 
            try { // the next line is the error's line
                AccessToken acc = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken,
                        verifier);
            } catch (TwitterException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You creating `Twitter` instance only after user clicks on button, but try to work with it in `onResume()` method where it equals `null`. Read about activity lifecycle to avoid such errors https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: thank very much I understand my error...but you can me suggest some data structure to avoid this problem?

Comment: look at this - https://github.com/syndarin/SocNetApi. It using Twitter4j. Pay your attention that project was created before Android 4.0 released and somewhere could be network calls in UI thread which will cause an exception on Android 4.0 and greater.